# HTML/CSS, getting table cells to balance

Tags: html, css

I have a table formatted as:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Long list of info
      Line two
    </td>
    <td>
      Shorter list of info
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get them to both display from the top of 'tr'? I assume there's a way to stop automatic vertical alignment with CSS?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should include some CSS in my example, or link to the file on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if you have some questions how to use tables pls look some examples here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I got it working with 'vertical-align: top;'

Comment: In the future, I'd recommend not sharing w3schools links and pointing to the appropriate reference on MDN instead (it's curated more effectively and the information is just generally explained better.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Tables

Comment: Please include more than a link. Something as simple as a link is better as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify for future viewers, I got it working using:

CSS:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Long list of info
      Line two
    </td>
    <td>
      Shorter list of info
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[(Here's the fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nB3LM/)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to avoid CSS you can do the same thing inline with the depreciated valign tag.  Valign is not supported in HTML5 but is the recommended method if you are working within the context of an HTML email.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="110">
            Long list of info Line two
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            Shorter list of info
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could always use two rows if you can predict and control where your breaks are going to be and want to simplify the markup further.

Comment: Who said anything about an email?

Comment: Considering the structure is used commonly in emails I thought it would be a helpful addition for anyone whom comes across the question and wants to apply what they see to what they're working on, regardless the context.  I don't think answers are useful exclusively to the original author and with that mindset should be as thorough as possible.

Comment: I personally prefer good answers over HTML 2 answers for emails (which shouldn't use stuff like tables anyway). Besides, style attribute works in emails.